# JavaScript, document.getElementById not grabbing from form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I'm attempting to create a datetime-local input that will submit into a function that will convert it into different types later on. I've been attempting to check whether the function I am using is receiving the user input by throwing it into an alert, however every time I get the alert, the information is not displayed, with "[object HTMLInputElement]" in its place. Clearly I must be doing something wrong if my bugtest isn't even working properly

Below is my form and my script.

```
<form>
    Start Time:
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start">
    End Time:
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="convert()">
</form>

<script>
    function convert() {
        var sd = new Date();   //start date
        var sds = new String();
        var ed = new Date();   //end date
        var eds = new String();
        var sd = document.getElementById("start");
        alert(sd);
        var sds = document.getElementById("end");
            alert(sds);
        }
</script>
```

Does anything obvious stick out?

Comment: **getElement**ById returns an element, in this case a HTMLInputElement, so it works correctly. You might want to start using the browser's Javascript console for debugging and replace alert with `console.log`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply calling `getElementById` will return an **HTMLInputElement** object. To get its value, you need to call `.value`

```
var sd = document.getElementById("start").value;
```

and

```
var sds = document.getElementById("end").value;
```

You also declared the variable `sd` twice. Only once is necessary. This adds to the codebase and makes things less DRY. Also, instead of initializing a new string like this

```
var eds = new String();
```

Do this instead

```
var eds = "";
```

I updated and improved your code.

```js
var startValue = document.getElementById("start-value");
var endValue = document.getElementById("end-value");

function convert() {
    var sd = new Date();   // start date
    var ed = new Date();   // end date
    var eds = new String();
    var sd = document.getElementById("start").value;
    startValue.innerHTML = sd;
    var sds = document.getElementById("end").value;
    endValue.innerHTML = sds;
}
```

```html
<form>
    Start Time:
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start">
    End Time:
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="convert()">
</form>

<p id="start-value"></p>
<p id="end-value"></p>
```

Comment: I apologize if this answer wasn't helpful. If someone could explain the downvote, I would be more than happy to update it. I want to help users by giving the best answer possible

Answer (score 1):

YOu have declared the same variable twice, var sd. one time you assigned it a Date() function and the second time you have assigned it a document.getElementByID(). and yes what the gental men said, innerHtml need to included to get the value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

First the click event is not the right chooce for what you are trying to achieve. Second youll have to bind events on the inpits rather then the form. You probably want to use a on change event. I also highly recommend using socument states and wleventbindings.

Comment: Sry ill fox this answer later. Writing on mobile phones clearly isnt one of my strengths.